# I've created a neural network in Python, does anyone know how to make it predict multiple timeseries simultaneously? Is this possible?

Tags: python, neural-network

I created a neural network in python that is predicting my time-series very well.

My issue is I want to be able to create a neural network that can predict multiple time series at the same time.

Is this possible and how would I go about it?

This is the code to build the NN for a single time series

```
nn_model = Sequential()
nn_model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
nn_model.add(Dense(1))
nn_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=2, verbose=1)
history = nn_model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=1, callbacks=[early_stop], shuffle=False)
```

Any ideas about how to convert this to run for multiple time series?

Comment: Can you share details about the dataset you have taken?

Comment: are the multiple time series you want to predict somehow correlated? does one depends from one or more of the others or are they independent from each other?

Comment: Essentially, I have energy consumption data for multiple different customers. I have created a neural network to that is trained with the data for one customer and can predict for that one customer. Is it possible to then train and predict for multiple customers at the same time?